# Using ARRAYFORMULA with COUNTIFS?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I was wondering if there was a way to do this so that I would not have to manually drag the equation out across the whole spreadsheet.

Currently, I have in my cell:
`=COUNTIFS(actorsOfMovies, $K2,helperColumns,L$1)` where actorsOfMovies and helperColumns are both `291x3` arrays.

Right now I am dragging this formula from `B2 to S32` in the final_chart spreadsheet. I was wondering if there was a way that I could do using the `ARRAYFORMULA`so that I would not have to drag it?

Here is the document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iLFbnXWiOh4PSZ-6yFXpQHgukry8AG5-M3WyBofBhzU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, it would help if we could see some example data. Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet here ?

Comment: Yep give me a second!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iLFbnXWiOh4PSZ-6yFXpQHgukry8AG5-M3WyBofBhzU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

in the spreadsheet you shared, on a new sheet (tab), try this formula (making use of a helper column you created on sheet "question_3":

```
=query(ArrayFormula({transpose(split(concatenate(moviestats_med!E2:G&char(10)),char(10))),transpose(split(concatenate(rept(moviestats_med!D2:D&char(9), 3)),char(9)))&{"",""}}), "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 matches '"&join("|", question_3!F2:F)&"' and Col2<>''  group by Col1 pivot Col3")
```

If you want the same result, without the use of any helper column (on sheet question_3), try:

```
=query(ArrayFormula({transpose(split(concatenate(moviestats_med!E2:G&char(10)),char(10))),transpose(split(concatenate(rept(moviestats_med!D2:D&char(9), 3)),char(9)))&{"",""}}), "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 matches '"&join("|", query(query(ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate(moviestats_med!E2:G&char(10)),char(10)))&{"",""}), "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1"), "select Col1 where Col2 >4"))&"' and Col2<>''  group by Col1 pivot Col3")
```

Hope that helps ?

EDIT: forgot to mention: you can't have empty cells in the actor's ranges (E2:G). Instead use a "/".